# Grub not showing after installing Elementary OS alongside Windows 10 [UEFI]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, windows-10, grub

I've tried to install elementary OS alongside Windows 10 in a UEFI machine. I first did it with Secure Boot enabled, using the "something more" option. I configured the root and swap partitions as I always do. But the strange thing is, when the installation ended and the machine was rebooted, Grub did not showed up and Windows was loaded instead. Then I retried disabling Secure Boot, and the same thing happened, so I loaded the live cd and reinstalled and updated grub from a chrooted partition as seen here: same result. I get the same results with Ubuntu 15.10.

Can someone point me in the rigth direction? What am I missing here?

My machine is an Alienware X51 R3 with a Samsung’s PM851 M.2 SSD and Windows 10 installed. I have previously succeded double-booting Windows 10 + Elementary OS in an Alienware X51 R2 and a Samsung EVO 840 SSD.

Comment: If you are trying to install Ubuntu, you may wish to try BootRepair, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  It would be interesting to see whether this works: if it does, then we know it has nothing to do with BIOS,SecureBoot, and so on.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the answer is, but I'm pretty sure it's in this other answer somewhere: [dual-boot - Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/129271)